# SVG filter makes element invisible in Safari and mobile Chrome

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I have following SVG filter:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <defs>
      <filter id="blurlayer" width="110%" height="100%">

        <feGaussianBlur  stdDeviation="4" result="blur"/>


        <feImage id="feimage" xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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" x="-5%" y="0"  height="300px" result="mask" />

        <feComposite in2="mask" in="blur"  operator="in" result="comp" />

        <feMerge result="merge">
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
          <feMergeNode in="comp" />
        </feMerge> 

      </filter>
    </defs>

</svg>
```

and apply it to element via CSS:

```
.filtered {
  -webkit-filter: url(#blurlayer);
  filter: url(#blurlayer);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This works in Chrome and Firefox on desktop but doesn't work in desktop/mobile Safari and mobile Chrome. I assume this can be syntax issue but can't see it, please advise.

Codepen link https://codepen.io/75bytes/pen/eyGKMx

Answer (score 1):

It seems applying feImage to HTML elements seems to be impossible in Safari. I ended up with workaround for Safari and mobiles and use overlay element and CSS property `backdrop-filter` and `pointer-events:none` to pass events to masked element:

```
#backdrop {
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```